# Android app design: write correct intent filter

Tags: android, intentfilter

I'm trying to write correct intent filter.

I'm basically familiar with intents, they work fine in my app, but i want to know the better way to do it. Here's what i need to do:

I have an application that owns some data. (data from ECU, engine control unit) There's two Activities: one Activity can display data as a digits, and another can display it as a graphs.

Let's see on the first activity.

1. **What does it do?** It displays.
2. **What does it display?** ECU data.
3. **How does it display this data?** as a digits.

The second activity is almost the same, but third item is different: it displays data as a graphs.

So, I want to be able to send intent that specifies exatly all info, just like "*Hey Android, I need to display ECU data as a digits*", and then first activity should be opened.

And I also want to be able to send intent that specifies only first two items, just like "*Hey Android, I need to display ECU data*", and then android should ask user what activity should be opened.

My app also should be able to respond to other apps.

What's the better way to achieve all this?

**UPDATE:** Here's my xml. What should i specify in `<intent-filter>`?

```
  <activity
     android:name=".MyActivity"
     >

     <intent-filter >
        <!-- what should i specify here? -->
     </intent-filter>
  </activity>
```

**UPDATE 2:** Here's what i'm trying to do: I have an application with `Service` that communicates via bluetooth with remote device and receives ECU data. There's some simple Activities that can display this data: as I already said, one can display digits, another can display graphs. This application provides `AIDL` interface for any another application to be able to get ECU data too.

As I said, these Activities is quite simple, they provides just basic user interface.

Say, one man wants this data to be displayed like moveable-pointer indicator. No problem: he can write his own `Activity` that will bind my `Service`, get data from it and display just how he wants.

Then, if i send `Intent` like "*Hey Android, I need to display ECU data*", then Android should ask me what Activity should be opened, and I want to be able to see this new `Activity` too.

Comment: I think you're unclear on how Intents and Activities work. TJ's answer below looks correct for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i found myself what i looked for.

in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
   android:name=".MyActivityForDigits"
   >

   <intent-filter >
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <data android:mimeType="ru.orionspb.bk100_iface_android/car_data" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <category android:name="ru.orionspb.bk100_iface_android.category.DIGITS" />
   </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
   android:name=".MyActivityForGraphs"
   >

   <intent-filter >
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <data android:mimeType="ru.orionspb.bk100_iface_android/car_data" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <category android:name="ru.orionspb.bk100_iface_android.category.GRAPHS" />
   </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And then i can say "*Hey Android, I need to display car data*" just like that:

```
     Intent mIntent = new Intent();
     mIntent.setAction("ru.orionspb.bk100_iface_android.action.VIEW");
     mIntent.setType("ru.orionspb.bk100_iface_android/car_data");
     mIntent.addCategory(android.content.Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);

     startActivity(mIntent);
```

If i want to say "*Hey Android, I need to display car data **as a digits***", i need to replace `CATEGORY_DEFAULT` with my own category:

```
     Intent mIntent = new Intent();
     mIntent.setAction("ru.orionspb.bk100_iface_android.action.VIEW");
     mIntent.setType("ru.orionspb.bk100_iface_android/car_data");
     mIntent.addCategory("ru.orionspb.bk100_iface_android.category.DIGITS");

     startActivity(mIntent);
```

And that's it. Of course, i can replace `DIGITS` with `GRAPHS` to open `MyActivityForGraphs` instead of `MyActivityForDigits`. It works just like i want it to work.

Comment: Awesome :) Glad you got things setup how you wanted!

Answer (score 2):

If you're passing information between activities within your own application; it's better to use Bundles (Or you could use SharedPreferences, or read/write to memory but I find bundles easier)

```
First activity:

Intent i = new Intent().newClass(first.this, second.class);
i.putExtra("keynamehere", value);
startActivity(i);

Second activity:
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
b.getString/getInt/getByte/etc("keynamehere");
```

If you want to work with custom Intent's - check this question out: [Filter Intent based on custom data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957519/filter-intent-based-on-custom-data)

I haven't had a chance to play around with it yet, but I think that should help you out - from the looks of it, it seems that they have a 'sender and receiver' like you are trying to do.

Comment: Let me know if that answers your question or not :)

Comment: not really =) I know about extras, but now i have not to pass any such info between activites. I need to know what should i specify in `<intent-filter>` section. I just updated my question.

Comment: Hm, I'm confused on why extras will not work for what you are attempting to accomplish? 

You want to push data from the digits to a graph, and graph to digits - correct? You should be able to use an extra to push them back and forth, and then onCreate() use those values to manipulate your activity - e.g. Say you want to display the digits x=y from x=1-10 You start out displaying your digits on the first one, and then for the second, either push your info (what you want to display, like x=y from x=1-10) or end data (x=1-10, y=1-10) and then create your data with the info given.

Comment: An <intent-filter> (I haven't used one yet, but from what I understand from the dev page: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html ) allows your activity to respond to intents of a certain type, like how we call new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND) if we want to open a dialog to let us choose an activity that can respond to the ACTION_SEND intent (Such as Gmail, since people use this for sending an email normally). I can only think of using <intent-filter> if you're looking to have your app respond to other apps. Feel free to give us more info! :)

Comment: Yes, actually, my app should respond to other apps, that's true. Sorry that i didn't say it before.

Comment: Okay, cool. So what exactly are you trying to do then? You have separate apps? Can you be very specific on what you want to do and I'll try my best to help you out :)

Comment: I posted an update - check it out and let me know if that helps :) Sorry I have to be short, at work right now and can't play around with it to make sure that's what you want.

Comment: After all, I found myself what i need. Please check my own answer to this question if you are interested. And thank you very much for trying to help! =)